# develop complex function to power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to expand the function $$
f(z)=\frac{2 i}{2+i+z}
$$ to power series near $z_0=0$ and $z_0 =1$

I wanted to bring it to the form of "something" $\cdot$ $\frac{1}{1-az}$ and than get expression of geometric series.

\begin{align}
f(z) & =\frac{2 i}{2+i+z}=\frac{2i}{2+i}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2+i}}  \\[8pt]
& =\frac{2i}{2+i}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{i(2i-1)}}
=\frac{2i}{2+i}\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty} \left( \frac{1}{i(2i-1)} \right)^nz^n
\end{align}

I am not sure how should I continue from here, I am stuck with that constant before the sum, I need to bring in a some way into the sum so I will be able to determine my $a_n$.

I would also like for an help for $z_0=1$ if possible.

Comment: It may help to note $c\sum b_n z^n =\sum (c b_n) z^n$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician srry it was typo, fixed

Comment: Yes but you haven't used my first comment

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am not seeing how is it possible to apply it.

Comment: ???? I have shown you how you "bring a constant into the sum"

Comment: @ancientmathematician can you write how my $a_n$ going to looks like?

Comment: You're done with the part about $z_0=0$ as soon as you write $a_n = \dfrac{2i}{2+i} \cdot \left(\dfrac1 {i(2i-1)}\right)^n.$ Multiplication distributes over $\sum. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy hmm I see. there is no another way to sipmlify the expression? after all i need a series so I will be able to calculate the radius of convergence

Comment: The constant won't affect the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is correct, but I think you could make it easier:
$$\begin{align}
f(z) & =\frac{2 i}{2+i+z}=\frac{2i}{2+i}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2+i}}\\
&=\frac{2i}{2+i}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{(2-i)z}5}\\
&=\frac{2i}{2+i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{2-i}5\right)^nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{2i}{2+i}\right)\left(\frac{2-i}5\right)^nz^n
\end{align}$$
The radius of convergence is $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac5{2-i}\right\rvert=\sqrt5$$

To get the power series about $z=1$, just start by writing $$f(z)=\frac1{3+i+(z-1)},$$ and then take analogous steps.

Comment: Actually, there was no need to convert $\frac1{2-i}$ to $\frac{2+i}5$ either.  I could have just left it as it was.  That would have been simpler yet.